# How does this `++` implementation by `foldr` work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I am learning Haskell with *programming in haskell* from Channel 9 Lectures. In chapter 7, the professor implemented his own `++` operator using `foldr` by

```
(++ ys) = foldr (:) ys
```

and his reasoning is

```
  xs ++ ys = foldr (:) ys xs
= (++) ys xs = foldr (:) ys xs
= (++ ys) = foldr (:) ys
```

Here is the blackboard

[image]

I got confused here why `xs ++ ys` functions the same as `(++) ys xs`. And I let `xs = [1,2,3]` and `ys = [4,5,6]` and run them by runhaskell, they just produce different answers:

```
> main = print $ [1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
> main = print $ foldr (:) [4,5,6] [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
> main = print $ (++) [4,5,6] [1,2,3] 
[4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

So what did the professor actually mean in his reasoning?

By the way, I am trying to induce by myself like the following:

```
  xs ++ ys = foldr (:) ys xs
= (++) xs ys = foldr(:) ys xs
```

`foldr(:) ys xs` at the right part of the equation means for each `y` in this `Foldable` `ys`, apply `:` to `y` and `xs`, which is actually what's done on the left side. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: You can also think of `foldr k z xs` as replacing all the `:` in `xs` with `k`, and `[]` with `z`. So `foldr (:) [3, 4] [1, 2]` takes `1 : 2 : []` and replaces `[]` with `[3, 4]`, giving `1 : 2 : [3, 4]` = `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, your reasoning is correct - there's an error in the video:

```
xs ++ ys = ...
= (++) ys xs = ...
```

should really be

```
xs ++ ys = ...
= (++) xs ys = ...
```

If you look at the comments to the [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals/C9-Lectures-Dr-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-7-of-13), you'll notice that [Tom Lokhorst pointed out this error (among several others)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals/C9-Lectures-Dr-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-7-of-13#c633936524210000000).